# Kubernetes get the full pod name as environment variable

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I know that I can define something like this to get the pod name in my containers:

```
env:
- name: POD_NAME
  valueFrom:
     fieldRef:
       fieldPath: metadata.name
```

But when I run: `$kubectl get pods`

I have a different result, something like: `uipod-5d6795db87-cxxkg` which corresponds to `<replicatset name>-cxxkg`.

Is it possible to get that full name (`uipod-5d6795db87-cxxkg`) as environnement variable? Instead of only the pod name (`uipod`).

Thanks a lot

Comment: `uipod` is not the Pod name. Assuming you're deploying a Deployment, it's probably the Deployment name. When I create a Deployment with the same snippet as what you have above, `POD_NAME` does indeed get set to the full Pod name, not the shorter Deployment name. Can you provide a set of YAML config files and commands to run where you reproduce the issue you're claiming to see?

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta  You are right, I mixed my deployment and pod config

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly set environment variable with pod name, its already present inside pod as an environment variable called `HOSTNAME`.

For example

```
$ kubectl run nginx --image=nginx
kubectl run --generator=deployment/apps.v1 is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectlrun --generator=run-pod/v1 or kubectl create instead.
deployment.apps/nginx created
$
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-7bb7cd8db5-kddbs   1/1     Running   0          12s
$
$ kubectl exec -it nginx-7bb7cd8db5-kddbs bash
root@nginx-7bb7cd8db5-kddbs:/#
root@nginx-7bb7cd8db5-kddbs:/# env | grep HOSTNAME
HOSTNAME=nginx-7bb7cd8db5-kddbs
root@nginx-7bb7cd8db5-kddbs:/#
```

*NOTE: As you can see `HOSTNAME` environment variable already have the exact pod name set.*

Comment: Exactly what I need.

Comment: Is there any piece of documentation that mentions explicitly that HOSTNAME environment variable is set? In other words, is this a Kube-provider-specific behavior or it's part of some general spec?

Answer (score 0):

The [official Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-environment/) does NOT specify that pod name is provided in `HOSTNAME` environment variable. It only mentions `hostname` command and `gethostname` function call in libc:

> The hostname of a Container is the name of the Pod in which the Container is running. It is available through the hostname command or the gethostname function call in libc.

So while in practice many Kubernetes distributions do set it, for maximum compatibility it's better to stick to the spec.

Standard libraries for many programming languages rely on `gethostname` function call in libc. For instance in Java `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()` [does it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69435693/15647).